# Sql merge some rows in query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to leave only one row, example, one of #4 and #7 from query result. First row priority.
Some of the fields are needed from the first row (4) and some from the second (7)
Communication goes across the field "parent_refill_transaction_id" and "parent_withdraw_transaction_id" like pivot.
And at the same time leave all the other records

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are completely different problems. I've removed these conflicting tags; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the (R)DBMS you are really using.

Comment: Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Larnu sorry, edited

Comment: Now you've removed the image, but not added a copy of it in a *consumable* format.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you have a result-set which has to be filtered (you're decreasing amount of rows in it) - "group by" and "row_number + partition by" are the best

"row_number + partition by" - better suits when we are selecting "the whole row" from several ones
"group by" - when we want to take some fields from one row and other fields from other rows (in a group)

For example, for table:

```
create table payment (
    id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
    transactionId int not null,
    title nvarchar(100) not null
)

insert into payment 
    (transactionId, title)
values
    (1, 'www'),
    (2, 'qq'),
    (3, 'eeee'),
    (1, 'r')
```

"row_number + partition by":

```
;with cte as 
(
    select 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by transactionId order by id asc) as rn
    from 
        payment
)
select * from cte where rn = 1
```

"group by":

```
select
    min(id) id, max(title) title, transactionId trans
from payment
group by transactionId
```

Which variant to choose - depends on your requirements / business needs